# How to find the complexity of 3 nested loops

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the following for loops:

```
for i = 1 to n
  for j = i to n
    for k = i to j+1
```

I think that the complexities for the first and second loop are n and n(n+1)/2 respectively but I’m really stumped as for how to figure out the complexity of the third one. How do I go about finding the complexity for it when both initial and end values are dependent on the previous loops?

Comment: You can start by trying different values of `n` and counting the number  of executions of the third `for`. Looking at the values should tell you something. Once you have an idea of a general form prove by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace each loop with a summation. Do some math...

[image]

**PS:**
These can help:

[image]

[image]

[image]